# How to use unified_message_sync with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception, facebook-fql, message

I can't find any thing about unified_message_sync in the web.
Just in Facebook Developer @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message_sync/

As I see there is an example but it didn't work : `SELECT ... FROM unified_message_sync WHERE thread_id = ... AND <min>action_id = ...`

I tried some requests like: 
`SELECT body FROM unified_message_sync WHERE thread_id = xxx and action_id = xxx`

The returned error is :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

SELECT body FROM unified_message_sync WHERE thread_id = xxx and action_id > xxx